# Finding two items (with the same index) in two lists

Tags: netlogo

I'm currently looking to develop two lists on Netlogo. Each list consists of x and y co-ordinates of a turtle - The lists populate whenever the turtle moves.

Therefore, if we combine the lists, they should form the total x and y co-ordinate of the turtle. Below is how I've attempted to do this:

```
    foreach mylistx[
      set n n + 1
      if (round xcor - 1) = ? [

        foreach mylisty [
          set i i + 1
          if (round ycor - 0) = ? and i = n [
            ;;do something
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

This is however, not working. I've attempted to create two numbers which identify the index numbers of each loop, and if they match - that is the co-ordinate of the turtle position.

Any help to solve this question will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Why not just store a single list of patches or at least a list of pairs (lists), if you wish to keep track of a turtles past locations?  What purpose is served by storing the two coordinates separately and then reconstituting them?

Comment: You can loop over both lists together with `(foreach mylistx mylisty [ ... ])` (parens required, since we're supplying `foreach` with a different number of inputs than usual. inside the loop the x and y coordinates will be `?1` and `?2` respectively